# Excel – Programatically get the data used in a chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have a big set of  charts that all use different collections of series in a single large Excel spreadsheet.

For each chart, I need to provide a data table containing **only the data used in that chart**. So if Chart A shows 20 data points for each of 4 categories, the end result I want is a table with 20 rows and 4 columns—exactly 80 cells, the data points that appear in the graph. (Plus a row and a column for the series titles.)

The way I do this now is by right-clicking on chart series and using `Select data` to highlight the underlying series. Then I copy that series off to the side, then repeat until I have compiled the table.

Needless to say, this is extremely time-consuming, and highly susceptible to human error. Is there a way to do this programmatically using VBA or anything else?

Comment: Have you tried doing this manually and recording your actions as a macro? When I did, I found that the single command `ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (5)` did a lot of magic. Maybe something similar will work for you?

Comment: Look at the methods to the [`Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213725(v=office.11).aspx) object, specifically `Chart.XValues`, `Chart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues`, and `Chart.SeriesCollection(i).YValues`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be more than enough to get you started. You will need to modify it to your purposes, but this will introduce you to the properties that you need to use.

How you structure the "exported" data is ultimately up to you. I give an example of how to write that out to a worksheet with the `Application.Transpose` function, but you will need to modify that part to suit your needs.

```
Sub DebugChartData()

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim srs As Series
Dim lTrim#, rTrim#
Dim xValAddress As String

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects  '## iterate over all charts in the active sheet
    For Each srs In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection  '## iterate over all series in each chart
    '## The following given only to illustrate some of
    '    the properties available which you might find useful
    '    You will want to print these out to a worksheet, presumably,
    '    but I don't know how you intend to arrange these, on what
    '    sheet, etc, so I will leave that part up to you :)
        Debug.Print srs.Name
        Debug.Print vbTab & srs.Formula  '# probably not so useful to you but I include it anyways.
    '##  You could parse the formula...
        lTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",", InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",") - 1, vbBinaryCompare) + 1
        rTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",")
        xValAddress = Mid(srs.Formula, lTrim, rTrim - lTrim)
        Debug.Print vbTab & xValAddress
    '## , but that hardly seems necessary. You could convert the array of
    '   values/xvalues in to a delimited string and then do a text-to-columns on the data
        Debug.Print vbTab & Join(srs.XValues, vbTab)
        Debug.Print vbTab & Join(srs.Values, vbTab)
    '## Or, you could use Application.Transpose to write out on a worksheet
        'Qualify this with the appropriate Destination sheet, also make the destination variable
        ' as you accommodate multiple series/charts worth of data.
        Range("A1").Resize(UBound(srs.XValues)) = Application.Transpose(srs.Values)

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, can I remove all the lines between `Debug.Print vbTab & srs.Formula ` through the `hardly seems necessary` comment, as long as there aren't formulas involved?

Comment: Yes you can remove those lines. I put several examples in this code just to show various ways of accessing parts of the chart's data.  Those lines, in particular, are probably not the methods you would want to use.

Comment: @supertrue have you had a chance to try this out? If so, and it's helpful for you, please consider "accepting" this answer. If you have trouble with it, let me know and I can help revise.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example from my graphing.  The only thing is you have to set up the first few rows in "Select Data" this will define the rest.

```
    Max = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 13
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("A4:A" & Max)
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets(2).Range("B4:B" & Max)
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Comet"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("C4:C370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Sheets(2).Range("D3:D370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Mercury"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("E4:E370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = Sheets(2).Range("F4:F370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Venus"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("G4:G370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = Sheets(2).Range("H4:H370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "Earth"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(5).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("I4:I370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = Sheets(2).Range("J4:J370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(5).Name = "Mars"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(6).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("K4:K370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = Sheets(2).Range("L4:L370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(6).Name = "Jupiter"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(7).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("M4:M370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(7).Values = Sheets(2).Range("N4:N370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(7).Name = "Saturn"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(8).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("O4:O370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(8).Values = Sheets(2).Range("P4:P370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(8).Name = "Uranus"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(9).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("Q4:Q370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(9).Values = Sheets(2).Range("R4:R370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(9).Name = "Neptune"
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(10).XValues = Sheets(2).Range("S4:S370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(10).Values = Sheets(2).Range("T4:T370")
    Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(10).Name = "Pluto"
```

Comment: This seems to be either not at all what OP asked for, or the exact opposite of what OP asked for. Your code demonstrates how to take Range arguments in to `Series` properties.  OP needs to take the properties and translate them back out to a(nother) worksheet/table.